# Issues with Next.js File Uploads: Server Works in Postman but Not in the Application

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, postman, fetch-api

I'm encountering a puzzling issue with file uploads in my Next.js application. Strangely, while file uploads perform seamlessly using Postman, the same operations through my Next.js app do not yield error responses. Successful uploads work well in both scenarios.

### With postman:

**Successful File Uploads:**

- In Postman, I can successfully upload files when they are of type PDF and image.

**Error Response Handling:**

- Postman appropriately reflects error responses from the server when attempting to upload incorrect file types through any of the fields.

**Consistent Behavior:**

- All tests conducted in Postman yield the expected results, demonstrating the correctness of the server's behavior.

### In my Next.js application, I've observed the following behavior during file uploads:

**Successful Scenarios:**

- I can successfully upload files when choosing one image and one PDF file.
- Single-file uploads of either an image or a PDF file work as expected.

**Error Responses:**

- When attempting to upload two image files instead of one image and one PDF file, I receive an error response.
- Similarly, choosing two PDF files for upload results in an error response.
  No Response for MP4 File:

**Interestingly,**

- when attempting to upload an MP4 file, I don't receive any response.

**Server Status:**

- The server appears to be functioning correctly, as it handles other file types without issue.
- I suspect that the issue might be originating from my Next.js application. I am keen to identify and address this problem for a smoother file upload experience.
- Any insights or guidance on potential areas of improvement would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my server:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const multer = require("multer");
    const cors = require("cors");
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    
    //----------------------------------------
    const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        const fileType = file.fieldname === "coverImage" ? "images" : "books";
        cb(null, fileType); // Specify the destination directory based on file type
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname); // Use the original file name
      },
    });
    
    const validateFileTypes = (req, file, cb) => {
      if (file.fieldname === "book" && !file.originalname.endsWith(".pdf")) {
        console.log(file.originalname);
        console.log(file.fieldname === "book");
        console.log(!file.originalname.endsWith(".pdf"))
        return cb(new Error(`Only PDF files are allowed for the "book" field: ${file.originalname} is not a pdf file!`));
      }
    
      if (file.fieldname === "coverImage" && !file.mimetype.startsWith("image/")) {
        return cb(
          new Error(`Only image files are allowed for the "bookCover" field: ${file.originalname} is not an image file.`)
        );
      }
    
      // Accept the file
      cb(null, true);
    };
    app.use(
      multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: validateFileTypes }).fields([
        { name: "book", maxCount: 1 }, // 'images' field can have up to two files
        { name: "coverImage", maxCount: 1 }, // 'documents' field can have up to three files
      ])
    );
    
    //--------------------------------------
    
    app.post("/", (req, res) => {
      res.status(200).json({ status: "success", msg: "It's working!" });
    });
    
    // app.post("/upload", (req, res, next)=>{
    
    //   console.log(req.files);
    //   console.log(req.body);
    //   res.status(200).json({msg: "Files Uploaded Successfully!"});
    
    // })
    
    app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
      // res.status(400).json({error: `Can't find the root you are looking for my love: ${req.url}`})
      const err = new Error(`Can't find the root ${req.url} my love`);
      err.status = "fail";
      err.statusCode = 404;
      next(err);
    });
    
    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
      err.status = err.status || "error";
      err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
      // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.status(err.statusCode).json({ status: err.status, message: err.message });
      console.log(err.statusCode, err.status, err.message);
    
      next();
    });
    
    app.listen(4000);
```

And here is my next app:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const UploadComponent = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const sendFiles = async (fileData) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/", {
        method: "POST",
        body: fileData,
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        const errorResponse = await response.json();
        setMessage(`Error: ${errorResponse.message}`);
      } else {
        const responseData = await response.json();
        setMessage(responseData.msg);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error.message);
      setMessage("Error occurred while uploading files.");
    }
  };

  const handleFileUpload = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("book", event.target.book.files[0]);
    formData.append("coverImage", event.target.coverImage.files[0]);

    await sendFiles(formData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="max-w-md mx-auto mt-8 p-8 bg-gray-100 rounded-md shadow-md">
      <form onSubmit={handleFileUpload}>
        <label className="block mb-4">
          <span className="text-gray-700">Book (PDF):</span>
          <input
            className="mt-1 p-2 block w-full border rounded-md"
            type="file"
            name="book"
            
          />
        </label>
        <label className="block mb-4">
          <span className="text-gray-700">Cover Image:</span>
          <input
            className="mt-1 p-2 block w-full border rounded-md"
            type="file"
            name="coverImage"
            
          />
        </label>
        <button
          className="bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-600"
          type="submit"
        >
          Upload Files
        </button>
      </form>
      <p className="mt-4 text-gray-800">{message}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadComponent;
```